# Ram usage in MB for all running applications

Tags: android, memory-management

I have successfully found the available free RAM but i want to find Ram usage in `MB` for All running Applications.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android) link but I am not able come up with Solution.

What kind of functionality would this require?

Comment: Post some codes that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `dumpsys meminfo` to get memory usage.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());

// periodically execute dumpsys meminfo
out.writeBytes("dumpsys meminfo\n");
out.flush();

// read mem log and do some parsing job
while (reader.ready()) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    // you can parse the log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, Debug.MemoryInfo might rescue you, check out Android developer documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html)

Comment: can you put some of your code which you have so far?